# Nice way to print a dynamic duration to NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, duration, nstimeinterval

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fuzzy Date algorithm in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052951/fuzzy-date-algorithm-in-objective-c)
>   [How do I break down an NSTimeInterval into year, months, days, hours, minutes and seconds on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237778/how-do-i-break-down-an-nstimeinterval-into-year-months-days-hours-minutes-an)

I am interested in printing the playback duration of a media item like '1 hour' or '2 minutes 10 seconds' depending on how large the NSTimeInterval is (without having a fixed format). Poorly there isn't any class provided by Cocoa Touch.

Before wasting time with reinventing the wheel I want to ask if somebody can recommend me an implementation of that. I am sure this is something often used, but I can't find any library/snippet which provide such a functionality on the web.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I break down an NSTimeInterval into year, months, days, hours, minutes and seconds on iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237778/how-do-i-break-down-an-nstimeinterval-into-year-months-days-hours-minutes-an) or possibly [Fuzzy date algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052951/fuzzy-date-algorithm-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
- (NSString*)timeIntervalStringforDouble:(double)timeInterval {
NSString *intervalString=@"";
NSInteger hours = (int)floor(timeInterval/3600.0);
double remainder = timeInterval-(hours*3600);
NSInteger minutes = (int)floor(remainder/60.0);
NSInteger seconds = (int)round(remainder-(minutes*60));
NSString *temporalSegment = @"hour";
if (hours) {
    if (hours>1) temporalSegment = @"hours";
    intervalString = [intervalString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d %@ ",hours,temporalSegment];
}
if (minutes || hours) {
    temporalSegment = (minutes==1)? @"minute":@"minutes";
    intervalString = [intervalString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d %@ ",minutes,temporalSegment];
}
if (seconds || minutes) {
    temporalSegment = (seconds==1)?@"second":@"seconds";
    intervalString = [intervalString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d %@",seconds, temporalSegment];
}
return intervalString; 
}
```

Punctuate and format to taste.

Comment: I am sure that will work, but I hoped their will be a some mature library for doing that. :/